# Electric current and electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

If I were to create an thin electric current down towards the bottom of the Atlantic Ocean would it theoretically be able to create an electromagnetic field im kind of new to the science stuff and I’m trying to figure something out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are a number of wires running on the bottom of the Atlantic ocean creating electromagnetic fields (that attract some sharks to bite the cables).

Answer (score 1):

Current actually is mostly electromagnetic field in a sense as, after some electrons are brought into motion by some power source, the electrons "push" each other around via the EM-Field to create what we perceive as current. Actually electrons in a DC-stream are usually so slow, it would take them hours to travel 1m (see for example [this](https://web.pa.msu.edu/people/huston/phy294h/lecture_feb8.pdf)), so if there wasn't that "pushing" via the EM-Field, current would not work as it does.

Now this EM-Field can be described approximately by Maxwells equations, wich allow for some changing electromagnetic fields to propagate trough space even in the absence of any charge or current (electromagnetic waves), and they also allow for more "static" fields of static currents and charge distributions to extend into all of space, so technically, any currents or charge distributions will usually create some field extending trough all of space (in the nonrelativistic approximation).

However, fields of static or dynamic setups in some bounded region of an empty space will decay with at least $r^{-2}$ (even a laser from a laserpointer would spread eventually), and are thus only significant in the surroundings of the emitter.